# git and "Server aborted the SSL handshake" errors

Tags: git, ssl, github, ssh

Often when I want to push to my private repo I get a "Server aborted the SSL handshake" error. After several tries it often suddenly works. I was yet not able to find a solution on the internet.

If this weren't annoying enough today I wanted to install torch via `git clone https://github.com/torch/distro.git ~/torch --recursive`

It fails every time at the public *cutorch.git*

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/torch/cutorch.git/':
> Server aborted the SSL handshake fatal: clone of
> 'https://github.com/torch/cutorch.git' into submodule path
> 'extra/cutorch' failed

However when I execute this line by myself it works fine:

```
git clone https://github.com/torch/cutorch.git/ extra/cutorch
```

Now I have to restart the install process which fails because the folder already exists. So no torch for me unless this is fixed?

I have the latest version of git(2.8.1) installed and use Mac OS 10.11.4.

How do I fix this annoying SSL handshake error?

**Update**: It may be caused by my ISP. I have had phases where I had problems with HTTPS and iTunes Store connections as well.

Comment: For me it was a transient problem. I tried pushing again about 2 minutes later and it worked fine. That may not have been the case for the OP, but for some people who come here looking up this error message it's worth a try.

Comment: For me, all I needed to do was reboot my Mac.  Apparently some cache was fouling up the works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Often when I want to push to my private repo I get a "Server aborted the SSL handshake" error. After several tries it often suddenly works. I was yet not able to find a solution on the internet :(

It might be a problem of the different ssl version you are using.

In order to fix it generate a new ssl (`RSA`) certificate, and update your GitHub account with this new certificate.

### ***`Here is how to set it up:`***

- Generate a new ssh key. ***Set the -t to rsa** in order to avoid future connection problems.

  ```
  ssh-keygen -t rsa
  ```
- Once you have your generated in your `%HOME%/.ssh` directory ( windows: `Users/<your user>.ssh`), open it and copy the content of the `<keyname>.pub`

---

### ***`How to set up ssh key under your GitHub account?`***

- Login to GitHub account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (***`Settings`***)
  [image]
- Click on the `SSH keys and GPG Keys`
  [image]
- Click on the `New SSH key`
  [image]
- Paste your key and save

---

### ***`Note`***

After the first set up open terminal and run a `git fetch` so the key will be tested and added to your `known hosts` file.

Comment: Nice guide, however on git fetch: "Server aborted the SSL handshake"

Comment: I tinkered much around and today it worked. Maybe this is not the solution but it still helped therefore marking as accepted answer. Maybe there were just some issues at github's end.

Comment: After set ssh key, you need switch from https to ssh https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/

Comment: I had this error while executing command git fetch upstream on bitbucket repo. But as you mentioned trying 2nd time it magically worked without doing anything.

Answer (score 2):

This may help you:

Generate SSH Key: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

Then add it your git account: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone https://github.com/torch/distro.git ~/torch --recursive
```

I have just tried cloning(using the above command) and it worked fine. I see all the submodules are hosted on github.com only. It might be some temporary issue with the SSL certificate at github.com's end.

Or else, you can try cloning it via SSH if that works for you.

Sub-modules cloned:

```
Submodule 'exe/env' (https://github.com/torch/env.git) registered for path 'exe/env'
Submodule 'exe/luajit-rocks' (https://github.com/torch/luajit-rocks.git) registered for path 'exe/luajit-rocks'
Submodule 'exe/qtlua' (https://github.com/torch/qtlua.git) registered for path 'exe/qtlua'
Submodule 'exe/trepl' (https://github.com/torch/trepl.git) registered for path 'exe/trepl'
Submodule 'extra/argcheck' (https://github.com/torch/argcheck.git) registered for path 'extra/argcheck'
Submodule 'extra/audio' (https://github.com/soumith/lua---audio.git) registered for path 'extra/audio'
Submodule 'extra/cudnn' (https://github.com/soumith/cudnn.torch.git) registered for path 'extra/cudnn'
Submodule 'extra/cunn' (https://github.com/torch/cunn.git) registered for path 'extra/cunn'
Submodule 'extra/cunnx' (https://github.com/nicholas-leonard/cunnx.git) registered for path 'extra/cunnx'
Submodule 'extra/cutorch' (https://github.com/torch/cutorch.git) registered for path 'extra/cutorch'
Submodule 'extra/fftw3' (https://github.com/soumith/fftw3-ffi.git) registered for path 'extra/fftw3'
Submodule 'extra/graph' (https://github.com/torch/graph) registered for path 'extra/graph'
Submodule 'extra/graphicsmagick' (https://github.com/clementfarabet/graphicsmagick.git) registered for path 'extra/graphicsmagick'
Submodule 'extra/lua-cjson' (https://github.com/mpx/lua-cjson) registered for path 'extra/lua-cjson'
Submodule 'extra/luaffifb' (https://github.com/facebook/luaffifb) registered for path 'extra/luaffifb'
Submodule 'extra/luafilesystem' (https://github.com/keplerproject/luafilesystem.git) registered for path 'extra/luafilesystem'
Submodule 'extra/nn' (https://github.com/torch/nn.git) registered for path 'extra/nn'
Submodule 'extra/nngraph' (https://github.com/torch/nngraph) registered for path 'extra/nngraph'
Submodule 'extra/nnx' (https://github.com/clementfarabet/lua---nnx.git) registered for path 'extra/nnx'
Submodule 'extra/penlight' (https://github.com/stevedonovan/Penlight.git) registered for path 'extra/penlight'
Submodule 'extra/sdl2' (https://github.com/torch/sdl2-ffi.git) registered for path 'extra/sdl2'
Submodule 'extra/signal' (https://github.com/soumith/torch-signal.git) registered for path 'extra/signal'
Submodule 'extra/threads' (https://github.com/torch/threads-ffi.git) registered for path 'extra/threads'
Submodule 'pkg/cwrap' (https://github.com/torch/cwrap.git) registered for path 'pkg/cwrap'
Submodule 'pkg/dok' (https://github.com/torch/dok.git) registered for path 'pkg/dok'
Submodule 'pkg/gnuplot' (https://github.com/torch/gnuplot.git) registered for path 'pkg/gnuplot'
Submodule 'pkg/image' (https://github.com/torch/image.git) registered for path 'pkg/image'
Submodule 'pkg/optim' (https://github.com/torch/optim.git) registered for path 'pkg/optim'
Submodule 'pkg/paths' (https://github.com/torch/paths.git) registered for path 'pkg/paths'
Submodule 'pkg/qttorch' (https://github.com/torch/qttorch.git) registered for path 'pkg/qttorch'
Submodule 'pkg/sundown' (https://github.com/torch/sundown-ffi.git) registered for path 'pkg/sundown'
Submodule 'pkg/sys' (https://github.com/torch/sys.git) registered for path 'pkg/sys'
Submodule 'pkg/torch' (https://github.com/torch/torch7.git) registered for path 'pkg/torch'
Submodule 'pkg/xlua' (https://github.com/torch/xlua.git) registered for path 'pkg/xlua'
```

Comment: works for you, but not for me. That's why I'm asking for help :)
I don't think it's a temporary issue because my push issue is a problem for months.
Replacing https with ssh gives me "Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository."

Comment: Did you try `git clone git@github.com:torch/distro.git --recursive` ?

Comment: As other members suggested, you would need to add your SSH public keys to your github.com account and try again.

Comment: Hi, Can you also, try this? 

1. Log in to your Github account
2. Go to Settings -> SSH and GPG keys
3. Remove old or unused keys.

Comment: And also, I see github.com is facing some issues: https://status.github.com/messages

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by updating to latest version of MacOS (from Sierra to High Sierra). I guess that something outdated got updated and it started working directly. Maybe someone gets here today and experiences the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issues while cloning the repo, 
was struggling for few days on this issue in MAC osx environment. 
I have also recently changed my account password.

**Sharing the solution that worked for me:**
(comment all the proxies and un comment the required one alone)

1) installed the SSH key as mentioned above.

2) open  all the scripts having the proxy configuration in text pad and tiled them.  1).bash_profile, 2).gitconfig, 3) .npmrc 4).curlrc

3) comment all the proxy setting lines in all files by adding # in front

4)uncomment the one which is required - for me , i was doing a git clone from a secure server, hence i uncommented the [https] proxy line in .gitconfig file.

5) execute the clone command again, prompted for username and pass and clone was sucessful.