# Can not push commits to GitHub

Tags: git, ssl, github, ssh

I have tried many time to push my commit to GitHub, but it always failed. The error message is:

> fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/MyAccountName/MyRepositoryName.git/': Server aborted
>   the SSL handshake (128)

I have replaced the real account name and repository name with MyAccountName and MyRepositoryName for privacy reason.

By googling the problem, I found someone else have the same problem: [git and "Server aborted the SSL handshake" errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936678/git-and-server-aborted-the-ssl-handshake-errors)

I followed the steps to generate a new ssh key and add it to my account, but not worked for me.

I also followed the steps in https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/ and added the new regenerated ssh key to my account. Still not worked.

I have tired the above two approaches many times, and still got the same error message.

Just 3 or 4 hours ago, I could still push my commits to Github. Did I do something wrong? How can I fix it?

By the way, since I used GitHub client to push, I also tried to sign out and sign in again the Github client, but still can't push. (I also tried to use the git command in terminal, just got the same error message.)

Comment: It looks like a proxy issue. Check whether you have disabled/enabled the proxy in last few hours.

Comment: @love Yes, I have enabled a proxy, because if I do not enable proxy, I will get the error message: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/MyAccountName/MyRepositoryName.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out (128), though I do not need to enable proxy to push commits few hours ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have solved the problem by changing DNS server in the network setting!

Since I could still with work with GitHub before and I did not change anything in my account setting or proxy setting, I think it is not the SSL or proxy issue.

So I tried to use my phone's hotspot to push my commits, everything works well!

Then I realised that it maybe the issue of my network. The first thing came to my mind is DNS server, so I changed my DNS server to another public one and the annoying error message never shows again.

I do not know too much about network so I have no idea about why the new DNS server can work as expected. I just solve my problem.

Comment: I actually found my issue to be that I needed to reboot my computer and then all worked as before.

Comment: this is the second post about this issue where you keep posting rebooting fixes the problem. Rebooting is never a good fix since you don't ever know what exactly is causing the problem. What cache did you flush? shared memory, ipcs, what?