# I can't install the Watchman

Tags: github

```
$ brew install watchman

==> Cloning https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo.git
Cloning into '/Users/pcuser/Library/Caches/Homebrew/rust--cargo--git'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo.git/': Server aborted the SSL handshake
Error: Failed to download resource "rust--cargo"
Failure while executing; `git clone --branch 0.54.0 -c advice.detachedHead=false https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo.git /Users/pcuser/Library/Caches/Homebrew/rust--cargo--git` exited with 128. Here's the output:
Cloning into '/Users/pcuser/Library/Caches/Homebrew/rust--cargo--git'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo.git/': Server aborted the SSL handshake
```

I think the problem is the SSH authentication settings,
but I don't know what to do.
If there is a solution, please teach me.

Comment: Hello,

There is one answer in stack overflow community you might need this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936678/git-and-server-aborted-the-ssl-handshake-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think the problem is the SSH authentication settings,

Not is you are using an HTTPS URL: SSH settings would be ignored then

If you really want to try SSH, type your brew command [after this](https://gist.github.com/Kovrinic/ea5e7123ab5c97d451804ea222ecd78a):

```
git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

Then, that would use your [SSH settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36937053/6309).
Otherwise, the original error could be due to ISO or proxy. Not SSH.

Comment: I appreciate it very much! thank you! I was able to download!